# Is it possible to increase only the vertical size of a shape in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I have a shape (rounded rectangle) in PowerPoint 2007 of which I would like to increase the vertical size only (to illustrate de-bottlenecking). So, the width will stay the same but the height will grow (both from the top and bottom, so the centre will remain in the same location).

Custom Animation -> Emphasis only appears to change *the whole shape*.

Is it possible to increase only the vertical size (stretch the shape)?

This is during **animation** of the shape.

Comment: Wait, do you mean you wanted to grow the shape as an animation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No there's not, but you can approximate this visual using two objects

I don't think there's a native way to do what you're looking for, but this work-around might give you the same visual effect. This technique relies on creating two shapes: one for the starting size and one for the ending size, and then animating the end shape. Also, it may look better with a squared edged box, although I know you're using a rounded one.

1. **Create a box that will be your starting size**, set the fill color as appropriate and turn off the border.
2. **Create a second box at the right size and location for the end state,** set the fill and border the same as object #1, and layer it behind object #1.
3. Set the following animation parameters on the 2nd object:

   - Set the entrance effect to **"split"**
   - Set the direction to either **"horizontal out"** or "vertical out" (which will depend on the motion you want and the object orientation)

**When you preview the animation, you should see object #1 in the foreground and object #2 growing out from behind it straight up and down.**

Comment: There is a native way, as described in the other answers.

Answer (score 11):

With the object you want to "stretch vertically" selected, click the "add custom animation" button. Choose "emphasis," then pick the effect named "Grow/Shrink." You may have to expand the list of "emphasis" animations to see the "Grow/Shrink" effect. Within the custom animation window, as one of the selectable properties for this effect, there is a drop-down for "size." When you expand that drop down, you should also see three options at the bottom of the size presets to specify if you want the shape to grow horizontally, vertically, or both (both is the default).

I've used this to make an object appear to rotate around a horizontal line by setting the size to 0% and choosing vertical only.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to what you're asking, and this is how I did it:

- 1.- Create a rectangle
- 2.- In animations page, click on the Animation Pane item (you'll need it)
- 3.- Next click on the rectangle, and from the Add Animation drop-down menu, select Grow/Shrink (by default it will enlarge your whole
  shape, which you don't want)
- 4.- On the Animation pane, you'll see your new animation appear, click on that line and you'll see a small drop-down menu arrow appear
  to the right of the row. Click on that arrow.
- 5.- From the new drop-down menu, select Effect Options...
- 6.- From the Effect tab, under the Settings section, pick the drop-down menu under Size:
- 7.- Now click on the boxes you want: bigger, smaller, vertical, horizontal, etc